# How to test old iPad app in Resizable iPad simulator?

Tags: ios, ipad, ios-simulator, xcode6-beta6

I would like to test our old iPad App in new Xcode6-beta6's Resizable iPad simulator i.e. with  iPhone 6 1334 x 750 display or with iPhone 6 Plus 1920 x 1080 display sizes, but I am just not able to set the `Height`, `Width` textfields on the bottom. Keyborard comes up, but simulator always reset my values with defaults. What can be the reason?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to download the Xcode 6 GM version and you will get both iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus option to the iOS Simulator:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Although the accepted answer is correct for the OP's question, you may wish to test **other** sizes. As far as I can tell, they must be less than or equal to the original dimensions provided.

This will still let you test all aspect ratios, which is (IMO) the point.

[image]